# UITableView Custom Class programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

I'm wondering how this:
[image]

could be done programmatically? Is it just setting the uitableview datasource and delegate to the `FadingTableView` class? What exactly is going on by setting the custom class in IB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are telling IB that the table view instance is actually the instance of `FadingTableView`. 
and if you want to create this table view programmatically then use these line

```
FadingTableView *tableView = [[FadingTableView alloc] init.....];
```

Why you set that class in IB is because the IB has inbuilt objects thus `UITableView` but you want your table view which is not present in the IB thus you put your class name there so that it will create instace of `FadingTableView` instead of `UITableView`.
 And No it's not used for connecting datasource or delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate on your question as it does not signify it's purpose..I think you are asking the deifference between connecting the datasource and delegates via xib and declaring it programmatically via a class.There is not much of a difference between them but logically if you see IBAction and IBOutlet are just the identifiers to let the compiler know that the object has been defined via interface builder(now integrated with xcode in later versions of xCode).IBAction is defined to void while IBOutlet is just defined.Apple's definition is as:-

```
#ifndef IBOutlet
#define IBOutlet 
#endif  

#ifndef 
IBAction #define 
IBAction void 
#endif
```

Both act as identifiers for compiler that's all.It just tells the compiler that certain methods are defined via interface builder.

Comment: sorry if I was unclear. I am asking how to do what is happening in the screen shot above when there is no xib file for the uitableview.

Answer (score 0):

What this does is using a subclass of UITableView (apparently) that you have provided in your source code and instantiating it when the nib is loaded. IT does not mean `datasource` and `delegate` are connected.

To do the same thing in code you would have to remove the TableView from the xib file and create it e.g. in `viewDidLoad` of the ViewController representing that xib file using `[[FadingTableView alloc] init…]`, setting the `frame`, appearance, `delegate`, `datasource` and all other attributes manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object_setClass(tableView, [CustomClass class]);` and must include `#include <objc/runtime.h>`